# Visual studio 19 GLFW external symbol error

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2019, glfw, unresolved-external

I use the GLFW example from https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html
I get these errors

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: generic RPG game, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glClear referenced in function main
1>C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\foldrr\generic RPG game\x64\Debug\generic RPG game.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "generic RPG game.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I included the glfw3.lib and the headers too

I use the x64 windows precompiled binaries version 3.3.2 (latest version as of right now)

if I comment out `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` function in the example code the error goes away and I'm able to compile normally and by removing the `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` parameter in the function i get a `'glClear': function does not take 0 arguments` error

also if i comment out the function and try to render simple triangle i get a error too

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glBegin referenced in function main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_glVertex2f referenced in function main
```

I know that similar question has been asked before but I didn't find anyone with this weird behaviour

Comment: The functions you are missing are not glfw functions but OpenGL functions. Do you link against opengl32.lib?

Comment: Try what BDL said, you should be able to link to it directly as OpenGL should sit in your system32 and ready to link. Otherwise, make sure you're using the correct precompiled binaries for your specific compiler. Otherwise, try buliding glfw3 yourself